Distributed Amplifier Design: Model trans.-line and termination
I am working towards implementing a distributed amplifier and am struggling with the design of the input and output networks. I have the design bandwidth specified at 5Ghz, and gate and drain impedances and capacitances have been estimated.
How does one model the transmission lines and the termination resistances to absorb the reflections?
